# I'm trying to get the google calendar id but it is wrong

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get the calendar, but it's returning an error

> Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in

Below is my code, where I already have the auth2 access token

```
    require "../_lib/libraries/grp/googleCalendar/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig('../_lib/libraries/grp/googleCalendar/credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');


//$_SESSION['access_token'] = '';


if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  
  print_r($_SESSION['access_token']);
    
  // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
  //$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);   
    
    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            
        }   
        
    }   
  
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  
  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
  );
 
  //here the error occurs
  $calendar = $service->calendars->get('calendarid');
  echo  $calendar->getSummary();    
    
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
  $events = $results->getItems();   
    
  if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}   
  
    
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/scriptcase9/app/project_gestao/oauth2callback/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

it is part of obtaining the access token auth02 is working, but now I need the calendarid and the error returns as I explained above.

as said the access token is already working and is showing events correctly, but I need the calendarid.

Comment: Is this even prompting you to login?   check the location of credentials.json  Not found is not a response i would expect from a calendar.get  Have you tried get('primary')  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains the line

```php
  $calendar = $service->calendars->get('calendarid');
```

Hereby `'calendarid'` should either be replaced by a real id (of a calendar to which you have access!) or through a variable.

**Given that before you already defined `$calendarId = 'primary';` it makes sense to modify your code to**

```php
  $calendar = $service->calendars->get($calendarId);
```

Comment: but i'm trying to use the lib full calendar however it asks for this calendar id in addition to the api key i already have however i only have the access token i'm using auth2, i saw in the lib that i need this calendarid.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mixing up calendarId and clientId? The calendarId is not part of your authentication credentials. It is the "name" of your calendar. E.g. CalendarId@gmail.com or calendar Id@yourdomain.com

Comment: ah yes i think i'm mixing yes, pseh i need this clientid to put it in the full calendar but i don't know how to get it, to put it in api

Comment: as you can see in my code i already have access to the token with oauth2 but i need this clientid too

Comment: how do I get the clientid after the user authenticates? by api code

Comment: You need to provide YOUR clientId that you can retrieve from the GCP console when creating credentials.

Comment: Yes but I'm creating a web system for this and I want the user to be able to access this.